# Jquery: Problem passing XML to function using $.get

Tags: jquery

I seem to have an issue passing the xml i am reading to a function.. Basically i have this, this seems to work

```
    $.get("content/xml/faq.xml", function(test) {
        alert(test);// TEST CONTAINS THE XML
    });
```

but i really want to isolate the function and have the get call a new function but "data" in my function is undefined. I do end up in processFaq so the call back is working but data is empty

```
    $.get("content/xml/faq.xml", processFaq());

    function processFaq(data) {
       alert(data);  // DATA IS UNDEFINED
    }
```

Anybody know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $.get("content/xml/faq.xml", processFaq);
```

this should work

Comment: To add to this - `processFaq()` executes the function and passes the returned value, whereas `processFaq` will pass the function itself

Comment: Thanks antpaw, i am little confused so when i passed processFaq() - notice the brakets it didn't work but without brackets it did work.. I thought i supposed to always use brackets when calling a function ??

Comment: im not sure but i think somewhere inside the get function defenition its using eval(callback_function_name + '(data)'), but your right it needs to be more consistent